# ocserv error: vhost, you cannot mix multiple authentication method

Tags: centos, networking, vpn, openconnect, vhost

I'm trying to install [ocserv](https://gitlab.com/openconnect/ocserv) *(OpenConnect VPN Server)*, using script from [this repository](https://github.com/xhdix/openconnect-installer), on CentOS 8.1. Script automatically sets up server, certificate, user list and other settings.

After `install.sh` is run *(script content is below)*, i check the logs using `journalctl -u ocserv`, and this is the output:

```
Starting OpenConnect SSL VPN server...
Started OpenConnect SSL VPN server.
note: skipping 'pid-file' config option
error: cannot open file /etc/letsencrypt/live/208.xx.xx.xx/fullchain>
Parsing plain auth method subconfig using legacy format
error: vhost:default: you cannot mix multiple authentication method>
ocserv.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ocserv.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Error seems to be `error: vhost:default: you cannot mix multiple authentication method`, which is located in the [source code here](https://github.com/openconnect/ocserv/blob/master/src/config.c). There is also this error `error: cannot open file /etc/letsencrypt/live..` about certificate, not sure if it is important.

Where is `vhost:default` config file (about multiple authentication) is located at & how to fix this? Or am i misinterpreting the errors?

**PS**:
*If you need output of any command, let me know in the comments*

`install.sh` script

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# openconnect/anyconnect server (ocserv) installer in centos + let's ecnrypt 
# 
# bash install.sh -f username-list-file -n host-name -e email-address

usage()
{
    echo "usage:"
    echo "bash install.sh -f username-list-file -n host-name -e email-address"
}


###### Main

LIST=""
HOST_NAME=""
EMAIL_ADDR=""

if [[ $(dnf -q check-update | wc -l) > 0 ]] ; then
    echo 'You must be updated before this script.'
    echo 'Run: yum update'
    exit
fi

while [[ $1 != "" ]]; do
    case $1 in
        -f | --list )     shift
                    LIST=$1
                                ;;
        -n | --hostname )     shift
                    HOST_NAME=$1
                                ;;
        -e | --email )      shift
                    EMAIL_ADDR=$1
                                ;;
        -h | --help )         usage
                                exit
                                ;;
        * )                   usage
                                exit 1
    esac
    echo $1;
    shift
done

if [[ $HOST_NAME == "" ]] || [[ $EMAIL_ADDR == "" ]] || [[ $LIST == "" ]] ; then
  usage
  exit
fi

echo '[10%  ] Start installation...'
yum -q update -y  > /dev/null &
wait
yum install epel-release -y > /dev/null &
wait
yum repolist enabled > /dev/null &
wait
yum -q update --assumeno > /dev/null &
wait

yum install iptables-services -y > /dev/null &
wait

yum install ocserv certbot -y > /dev/null &
wait

echo '[20%  ] Request a valid certificate...'
certbot certonly --standalone --non-interactive --preferred-challenges http --agree-tos --email $EMAIL_ADDR -d $HOST_NAME &
wait

echo '[30%  ] Changing the default settings...'
sed -i 's/auth = "pam"/#auth = "pam"\nauth = "plain\[\/etc\/ocserv\/ocpasswd]"/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i 's/try-mtu-discovery = false/try-mtu-discovery = true/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i 's/#dns = 192.168.1.2/dns = 1.1.1.1\ndns = 8.8.8.8/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i 's/#tunnel-all-dns = true/tunnel-all-dns = true/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf & # !=  = DNS Leak
wait
sed -i "s/server-cert = \/etc\/pki\/ocserv\/public\/server.crt/server-cert=\/etc\/letsencrypt\/live\/$HOST_NAME\/fullchain.pem/" /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i "s/server-key = \/etc\/pki\/ocserv\/private\/server.key/server-key=\/etc\/letsencrypt\/live\/$HOST_NAME\/privkey.pem/" /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i 's/ipv4-network = 192.168.1.0/ipv4-network = 192.168.2.0/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i 's/#ipv4-network = 192.168.1.0/ipv4-network = 192.168.2.0/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i 's/#ipv4-netmask = 255.255.255.0/ipv4-netmask = 255.255.255.0/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i 's/max-clients = 16/max-clients = 128/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
sed -i 's/max-same-clients = 2/max-same-clients = 4/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
#sed -i 's/#mtu = 1420/mtu = 1420/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
#sed -i 's/#route = default/route = default/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf & # for use server like gateway = IP Leak
sed -i 's/no-route = 192.168.5.0\/255.255.255.0/#no-route = 192.168.5.0\/255.255.255.0/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf &
wait
#sed -i 's/udp-port = 443/#udp-port = 443/' /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf & # if there is a problem with DTLS/UDP
wait

echo '[40%  ] Adding iptables items...'
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT & # SSH port
wait
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT &
wait
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT &
wait
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT &
wait
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE &
wait
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.2.0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT &
wait
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.2.0 -j ACCEPT &
wait

echo '[50%  ] Activating the ip_forward feature...'
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf &
#echo "net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
wait

sysctl -p & # apply wihout rebooting
wait

echo '[60%  ] Adding users...'
echo ''
if [[ $LIST != "" ]] ; then
  while read -r -a line; do
    if [[ "${line[0]}" != "" ]] ; then
      echo "   For user ${line[0]} password updated with ${line[1]}"
      echo "${line[1]}" | ocpasswd -c /etc/ocserv/ocpasswd "${line[0]}" &
      wait
    fi
  done < $LIST
fi

echo '[70%  ] Preparing ocserv service...'

systemctl enable ocserv.service &
wait

systemctl mask ocserv.socket &
wait

cp /lib/systemd/system/ocserv.service /etc/systemd/system/ocserv.service &
wait

sed -i 's/Requires=ocserv.socket/#Requires=ocserv.socket/' /etc/systemd/system/ocserv.service &
wait
sed -i 's/Also=ocserv.socket/#Also=ocserv.socket/' /etc/systemd/system/ocserv.service &
wait

systemctl daemon-reload &
wait
systemctl stop ocserv.socket > /dev/null &
wait
systemctl disable ocserv.socket > /dev/null &
wait

echo '[80%  ] Start ocserv service...'
systemctl restart ocserv.service > /dev/null &
wait
#systemctl status ocserv.service &
#wait

#iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT & # Allow SSH port. Is this port really configured?
#iptables -P INPUT DROP & # If you have not ACCEPT the SSH port connection before, do not run this command! 
#wait

echo '[90%  ] Persistent iptables rules...'
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules &
wait

systemctl enable iptables &
wait

service iptables save &
wait

systemctl start iptables &
wait

echo '[100% ] Your VPN server is ready to use.'
echo ''
echo 'Please check the ocserv logs with: journalctl -u ocserv'
echo ''
```

Comment: The first error is `cannot open file /etc/letsencrypt/live/208.xx.xx.xx/fullchain>` and it could be possible that error is causing the later errors.  When you ran the install script, what was the output for when it tried to create the SSL certificate?  Does the file path `/etc/letsencrypt/live/$HOST_NAME` exist?  Have you tried running the `certbot` command manually with the correct variables?

Comment: It was some error, because hostname i provided was ip address of that vps